# coldfusion cffile upload replace no file selected

Tags: coldfusion, upload, cffile

In Coldfusion, using cffile upload, when a file is selected with the browse button the name of the selected file shows next to the button.  So far, so good.  When I submit the file for upload, the text changes back to "no file selected".  This is doubtless because we are submitting a form.

However, I'm submitting the form to the same page, and would like to see the name of the file selected instead of "no file selected" which is likely to confuse the user.

The code:

```
<form 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" 
 method ="post" 
 name   ="attupload"  
 action ="">

<cfoutput>   
   <table style = "margin-left: 40%">
  <tr><td>
   <input name="theupload" 
          type="file" 
          style = "font-family: comic sans ms; 
                   color: ##679C9C">        
  </td></tr>
  </table>
   <div style = "width:20%; margin:5% auto 5% 45%">  
     <input name  = "submit" 
            type  = "submit"
            class = "submitbut" 
            style = "font-size: 16px"
            value = "Upload File"> 
   </div> 

</cfoutput>   
</form>
```

The words 'no file selected' seem to be part of the input name = 'upload' field, but ColdFusion evidently takes control of it, and I cannot insert anything else.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can control the 'no file selected' note, so that I can put the name of the selected file back in that spot?  I have tried with javascript, but it is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Once a file has been selected, you can access its properties via JavaScript with the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications). You can't affect the value displayed next to the default `<input type="file">` field with JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

You should also avoid submitting forms to the same page. You should follow the process:

- Form page
- HTTP POST to form processing page.
- after form processing, `<cflocation>` (301 redirect) back to a list page or the form page.

When you post to the same page, the user can hit reload and be prompted to resubmit form data. This can be problematic in many situations. As an alternate, you can post the form data using `Ajax` or better, via [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This avoids a re-post on page reload and redirecting away from the current screen.

Also, you should avoid naming an `<input type="submit">` "submit". It can conflict with the JavaScript function `submit()` should you need to use it.

```
<input name  = "submit" 
        type  = "submit"
        class = "submitbut" 
        style = "font-size: 16px"
        value = "Upload File">
```

Comment: You are quite right that I should submit it to another page.  You say that I can't affect the value displayed next to the default <input type="file"> field with JavaScript. I'm wondering if you know another way to affect it?  Do you know how it works?  It does seem to be an HTML property, not coldfusion.

Comment: Re the input submit button, name = "submit" is a mistake and I've removed it.  As for type = submit, in all my code either there is a submit button with type = submit, or else I  submit the form with javascript using submit().  However, there is never both.

Comment: Traditionally, file input values were read only for security reasons. Not sure if that's changed with html5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html